# Changing JavaScript object structure with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript object `occurrences`;

```
var occurrences = { "Karri" : 1, "Ismo" : 1, "Harri": 4, ........} //it has 129 elements
```

I want to have a JavaScript object which looks like this:

```
var json = [{"Researcher":"Karri","Total":1},
           {"Researcher":"Ismo","Total":1},
           {"Researcher":"Harri","Total":4},......]
```

Any ideas about how to do it?

I have this method where I count the total numbers and I try to create JavaScript object.

```
function countPublicationsPerResearcher(fullnames){
    var occurrences = { };
    var json =[];

    for (var i = 0; i < fullnames.length; i++) {
        if (typeof occurrences[fullnames[i]] == "undefined") {
            occurrences[fullnames[i]] = 1;
            json.push({ "Researcher": fullnames[i],
                "Total": occurences[fullnames[i]]
            });
        } else {
            occurrences[fullnames[i]]++;
            json.push({ "Researcher": fullnames[i],
                "Total": occurrences[fullnames[i]]
            });

        }
    }

    //console.log(JSON.stringify(occurrences));//prints the occurences Json
    console.log(JSON.stringify(json)); //prints every iteration of the for loop, not overall result 

}
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use e.g. the following code:

```
var json = [];
for(var name in occurences){
  json.push({"Researcher":name,"Total":occurences[name]});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is get the keys from the `occurences` object and then construct your `json` list.

```
var json = [];
for (var key in occurences ) {
   if (occurences .hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      json.push({"Reseaercher" : key, "Total" : occurences[key]})
   }
}
```

if you are targetting only morden browsers you can do away with the check if it is a property of the object by extracting the keys using `Object.keys` and then pushing them into the array like this.

```
var json = [];
var keys = Object.keys(yourobject);
for (var i= 0; i < keys.length; i++ ) {
      json.push({"Reseaercher" : keys[i], "Total" : occurences[key[i]]})

}
```